# Could not initialize class FirebaseThreadManagers error on Firebase

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to manipulate my Firebase database from Google App Engine. Having followed tutorials, I'm getting the following error -

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseThreadManagers

Sometimes I see the following:

> ```
> org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
> ```

The error occurs at FirebaseOptions, as seen in my code below.

```
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("WEB-INF/MyApp.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://MyApp.firebaseio.com")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Here's the error in full

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.firebase.internal.FirebaseThreadManagers
>       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.(FirebaseOptions.java:147)
>       at com.example.name.myapplication.backend.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:55)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doRedirectedModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:415)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:128)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.forwardToServer(JettyContainerService.java:458)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.forwardToInstance(Modules.java:372)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DelegatingModulesFilterHelper.forwardToInstance(DelegatingModulesFilterHelper.java:95)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doRedirect(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:326)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:119)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>       at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Here's my build.gradle for the backend

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'


    appengine {
        downloadSdk = true
        appcfg {
            oauth2 = true
        }
    }
}
```

Top level build file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You tagged this with both "android" and "google-app-engine".  Seems like it should be one or the other, but not both.  Are you using the firebase-admin SDK on GAE?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'm using Google App Engine as a backend for my Android app. This is solely to do with GAE. I am using Firebase-admin SDK. It's one of my dependencies alongside firebase-database and firebase-core.

Comment: I just tested your exact `build.gradle`, and it worked fine for me. My gut feeling is that having the android plugins in your project has left it in an inconsistent state. I would recommend cleaning the project directory (`gradle clean`), and try to re-execute the app.

Comment: I've tried that and no difference. Gradle builds fine but when the Servlet is called I get that error. Please see my edit for another error I sometimes see, occurs at the same line - Firebase options.

Comment: can you please post your toplevel buildfile?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer - I've added it to the question

Comment: Can you remove all the Android plugins/dependencies from the build (also from the top-level gradle file) and try again? I was able to both build and call the servlet without issues, and the only difference is I'm not using any Android plugins.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka I've just done that. I've done some more digging and it's LoggerFactory being a restricted class which is blocking FirebaseThreadManagers and then causing the second error. I'll create a new question for this which is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the firebase-admin dependency alongside the other Android client libraries in a server app.  firebase-admin alone has everything you need to access Realtime Database in a JVM runtime.  The Android client libraries will be of no use in a server app because they require Android infrastructure.

Comment: If I remove the other Firebase dependencies, I get the error "Error:Version: 5.5.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin". In my top level build file, I have "classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'" under dependencies and "maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }" under repositories.

Comment: Also don't use the google-services plugin for non-Android gradle build.

Comment: I've made those changes but it's still giving the same error, unfortunately

Comment: Which one, the error from your question, or the error from the gradle plugin?

Comment: Please show the minimal build.gradle that will build your GAE app that has this problem.

Comment: I've done some further digging and think I know where the exact issue lies, please see this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608785/app-engine-loggerfactory-restricted-class-error-when-using-firebase-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error **NoClassDefFoundError FirebaseThreadManagers** regarding this line of code: `private ThreadManager threadManager = FirebaseThreadManagers.DEFAULT_THREAD_MANAGER;`

## Solution

Rebuild the *gradle* file. After the *gradle* file rebuilt the Kotlin app ran as expected.